# How to Display asset url In collection view ios

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, alassetslibrary

```
ALAssetsGroupEnumerationResultsBlock assetsEnumerationBlock = ^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) 
                 {
                if (result) {
             [assets addObject:result];
             ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [result defaultRepresentation];
            photoname=[rep filename];
            imageurl=[rep url];
            NSLog(@"result %@",result);
            NSLog(@"name %@",photoname);//Img0001.Jpg
            NSLog(@"name %@",imageurl);//assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=3B36DBC8-A2F7-4088-ADEF-A9E2FF8FD927&ext=JPG

            [print addObject:photoname];

            //NsuserDefaults
            //        NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:print];
            //        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:mutableArray forKey:@"test"];
            retArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:((NSMutableArray *) [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"test"])];
            NSLog(@"res %@",retArray);
           }
        };
    ALAssetsFilter *onlyPhotosFilter = [ALAssetsFilter allPhotos];
    [self.assetsGroup setAssetsFilter:onlyPhotosFilter];
    [self.assetsGroup enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:assetsEnumerationBlock];

}
```

Comment: Hi.. please post your question descriptively.. explaining what you've tried and what not worked..

Comment: I am Getting assert Url Like assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=3B36DBC8-A2F7-4088-ADEF-A9E2FF8FD927&ext=JPG   ...How to display that image in collection view

Comment: cellForItemAtIndexPath:                                                                      ALAsset *asset = arrayofurl[indexPath.row];
    CGImageRef thumbnailImageRef = [asset thumbnail];
    UIImage *thumbnail = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:thumbnailImageRef];                               It crashes:...........                                                         Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSURL thumbnail]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa3ccf10'

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the assets library to get the asset for the URL, and then get the image from the asset. Currently you are treating the asset URL as an asset rather than using the URL to get the asset:

```
[self.assetsLibrary assetForURL:assetURL resultBlock:^(ALAsset * asset) {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[asset thumbnail]];

    // use the image for something 
}
```

---

```
NSURL *assetURL = notequal[indexPath.row];

[self.assetslibrary assetForURL:assetURL resultBlock:^(ALAsset * asset) {
    UIImage *image = [UIImageimageWithCGImage[asset thumbnail]];
    UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:kImageViewTag];

    imageView.image = thumbnail;
}];

return cell;
```

Comment: In which place i need to add the above code..Plz let me know ...Im new to ios

Comment: In `cellForItemAtIndexPath` where you currently get the crash.

Comment: [ALAssetsLibrary assetForURL:notequal resultBlock:^(ALAsset * asset) {
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[asset thumbnail]];
        
        // use the image for something
   
   
    CGImageRef thumbnailImageRef = [asset thumbnail];
    UIImage *thumbnail = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:thumbnailImageRef];
    
    // apply the image to the cell
    UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:kImageViewTag];
    imageView.image = thumbnail;
        return cell;
    }
}

Comment: Well, you're getting the image twice now, and trying to call a class method on `ALAssetsLibrary` which doesn't exist. You need to get an instance of `ALAssetsLibrary` (hence `self.assetsLibrary` in my answer). You're familiar with OO, class methods, instance methods, instance variables?

Comment: Didn't spot that. You return the cell outside the block. Inside the block just set the image into the image view.

Comment: UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:kImageViewTag];
    imageView.image = thumbnail;
    }
    return cell;
        
     }        in return cell its shows error expected .

Comment: Looks like you're missing brackets: `thumbnail; }]; return cell; }`

Comment: [assetslibrary assetForURL:notequal resultBlock:^(ALAsset * asset)..........    (shows error)      AlAssetLibrary Declares the selector asseturl resultblock

Comment: Please update your question with a full block of code for the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` and copy and pasted error message

Comment: ALAsset*asset=notequal[indexPath.row];//ALAssetsLibrary* assetslibrary=[[ALAssetsLibrary alloc]init];
[self.assetslibrary assetForURL:notequal resultBlock:^(ALAsset * asset){UIImage *image=[UIImageimageWithCGImage[asset thumbnail]];CGImageRef thumbnailImageRef=[asset thumbnail];UIImage *thumbnail=[UIImageimageWithCGImage:thumbnailImageRef];UIImageView *imageView=(UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:kImageViewTag];imageView.image = thumbnail;}];return cell;}Error:[assetslibrary assetForURL:notequal resultBlock:^(ALAsset * asset)... (shows error)AlAssetLibraryDeclarestheselectorasseturl resultblock

Comment: @property (nonatomic, strong) ALAssetsLibrary*assetslibrary;

Comment: Because you're using the wrong type of parameter. Reading code in comments is not easy - please update your question with any new code.